# Is it possible to combine multiple s-functions into a single mex/dll

Tags: c++, matlab, dll

Recently I've been diving into Matlab and extending it with c++ code. So far I have had some success with the sample `timestwo` compiling it to a mex file via either the built-in mex commands as well as precompiled form with Visual Studio 2015. What I am really curious to discover is whether or not it's possible to actually bundle multiple `s-functions` into a single module.

Ideally I would like to have a single module that could contain between 10-20 routines of handwritten code, so this code could be used in a shared toolbox. What I haven't been able to find out though is how you force matlab to look for the function in a specific dll, it appears to always use the 'function name' as dll name. Are there any tips or examples about a multi-function setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bundle multiple s-functions into a single library. To share code you need to compile the shared functions as a separate library and then you can link the same library to each s-function. The shared library can be either static or dynamic depending on your design. You need to make sure all memory allocation for an instance of s-function is done by s-function possibly as DWorks and then pass the memory to shared functions for additional work.